# Connect MacBook Air M2 to two Apple Thunderbolt Displays

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, dock, thunderbolt-display

I have a MacBook Air M2 that I would like to connect to two Apple Thunderbolt Displays.

I know that it is not officially supported, but it seems like using a DisplayLink-compatible dock with the DisplayLink driver should make it possible to connect two non-thunderbolt displays.

However, I would like to connect my MacBook Air M2 to two Apple Thunderbolt Displays so it seems like I would need a dock that is both DisplayLink-compatible and has two thunderbolt ports (with display support).

Does such a dock exist?

Even better, does there exist a solution with daisy-chaining the displays?

---

The answers for [Does the 2020 Apple M1 MacBook Pro support 2x daisy chained Thunderbolt Displays?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406864/does-the-2020-apple-m1-macbook-pro-support-2x-daisy-chained-thunderbolt-displays) and [Is it possible to connect MacBook Air M2 to multiple external monitors?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457550/is-it-possible-to-connect-macbook-air-m2-to-multiple-external-monitors) only shows how to connect two (or more) non-thunderbolt displays.

Answer (score -2):

> I would like to connect my MacBook Air M2 to two Apple Thunderbolt Displays so it seems like I would need a dock that is both DisplayLink-compatible and has two thunderbolt ports (with display support).

#### You cannot connect an Apple Thunderbolt Display via a dock.

In a related question, I [answered how the Thunderbolt Display is actually a Thunderbolt “dock” with a display built in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268706/119271), not a display with a Thunderbolt connection.  It’s important to note that it’s not a DisplayPort or similar connection; this is why other computers cannot use it as a display.

To connect your MacBook Air M2, you would need to connect each Thunderbolt port via a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2/1 adapter directly to the Thunderbolt Display.  You should be able to daisy chain these monitors as via the Thunderbolt ports, but I haven’t tested this setup (in the past).

These displays saw very limited market adoption because of their limited nature. (IMO) You’d be better off getting  quality displays (DisplayPort capability) instead of trying to make these work.  You’ll have much more flexibility and compatibility going forward.

Comment: The number of supported external displays often confuses me. According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/index-macbook-air.html), both MacBook Air M2 models only support one external monitor. Apple also states this in the [MacBook Air M2 Tech Specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-air-m2/specs/). Your answer states two Apple Thunderbolt displays can be used through separate [adaptors](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter). I do not see how this would be possible with a MacBook Air M2 model.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Don’t think of the TB display as a monitor which uses DisplayPort through Thunderbolt.  It is a Thunderbolt dock with a monitor attached

Comment: You are missing my point. The specifications state only one external monitor. Your answer states two are possible.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Whenever I used these, they were more like external video adapters versus the built in GPU.  If memory serves, we would get 3 displays on an older MBP that could only support dual monitors.  It’s a confusing technology for the end user so when they died, we refused to re-order them.

Comment: The OP is asking a question specifically about a MacBook Air M2. Not an older MBP. So basically you a tell me you are not posting an answer to the OP's question. Instead, you are posting an answer to a question only known to you.

Comment: Same concept @DavidAnderson. I directly answered the question based on experience with a slightly different product.